# Null Pointer Exception when calling SetRegistrationListener

Tags: java, android, sip

The following is called after sipmanger.open  inside of a class extending thread. I checked to see if any of the parameters were null and they are not.

Any Ideas ?

```
private void setlisten() throws SipException {  
    sipman.setRegistrationListener(sipprofile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {

        public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = 10;
        }

        public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = 93;

            Log.d("register", "register done");
       }

       public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,String errorMessage) {
       }    
   });
}
```

Stack trace is as fallows:

```
f09-26 16:24:03.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11692): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
09-26 16:24:03.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11692): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 16:24:03.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11692):    at com.example.project2.sipwork.setlisten(sipwork.java:153)
09-26 16:24:03.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11692):    at com.example.project2.sipwork.run(sipwork.java:193)
```

Line 153:

`sipman.setRegistrationListener(sipprofile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {`

Line 193:

`setlisten();`

```
private SipProfile buildsip(JSONObject sipcreds ) throws JSONException, ParseException{

    SIP_USER = sipcreds.getString("username");
    SIP_PASSWORD = sipcreds.getString("password");

    if (sipman == null){
        sipman = SipManager.newInstance(context);
    }

    SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(SIP_USER, SIP_DOMAIN);  
    builder.setPassword(SIP_PASSWORD);
    builder.setAuthUserName(sipcreds.getString("username"));
    builder.setAutoRegistration(true);
    builder.setOutboundProxy(SIP_DOMAIN);

    SipProfile mSipProfile = builder.build();

    if (mSipProfile == null) {
        Log.d("problem", "that seems to be the problem");
    }


    return mSipProfile;
}


private void sipint(SipProfile sipprofile) throws SipException{

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.example.project2.INCOMING_CALL");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    sipman.open(sipprofile, pendingIntent,null);

    if (sipman == null){
        Log.d("problem", "found the null");
    }

SipProfile sipprofile = buildsip(sipcreds); 

        sipint(sipprofile);
        setlisten();
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat because something *is* `null` if you are getting a `NPE`?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the NullPointerException?

Comment: edited sipman.setRegistrationListener(sipprofile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that variables `sipman` and `sipprofile` are not `null`.

Comment: Mmh please, share your logcat and the line that throws the exception

Comment: Thanks. Can you post the code where you initialize `sipam` and `sipprofile`?

Comment: Mmh not sure but it looks that the `sipprofile` you're initializing is a local variable in method `sipint` (you're declaring it instead of just asigning). Any chance there's another instance variable `sipprofile` which still is `null`? Just in case, have you debugged step by step and evaluated the values of the variables?

Comment: yeah SipProfile sipprofile = buildsip(sipcreds);  should have been sipprofile = buildsip(sipcreds) not sure how I missed  that thanks !

Comment: Great it helped. Please, if the answer was helpful, consider upvoting/accepting so that other users can spot the solution too.